# django paginationated first page content different to root page content (with cache)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am paginating content based on a random queryset and I seem to be getting inconsistent results between the paginated first page `?page=1` and the root page itself.

So, I have my `ListView` like so:

```
class Some1_ListView(ListView):
    model = Some_Model
    template_name = "test1.html"
    paginate_by = 12
    context_object_name = "test1"
    queryset = Some_Model.objects.all().order_by('?')[:24]
```

My urls is like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('test1/', cache_page(500)(Some1_ListView.as_view()), name="test1" ),
]
```

and the template is paginated according to the django docs, nothing special. Now, when I go to:

```
localhost/test1
```

I get the first 12 objects. Now, When I move to the next page, onbiously, my url becomes:

```
localhost/test1/?page=2
```

This renders fine aswell. Now, when I go back to

```
localhost/test1/?page=1
```

I see that the results are not the same as `localhost/test1/`

So, `localhost/test1/?page=1 != localhost/test1/` Since I was caching the URL, I was expecting these two to be the same.

Can someone enlighten me as to why this is? and how do I get aorund it? Id like both these pages to show the same content (from cache).